# What the difference between filterOrElse and filterOrOther from Arrow?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

I could not find the difference between [filterOrElse](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core-data/arrow.core/arrow.-kind/filter-or-else.html) and [filterOrOther](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core-data/arrow.core/arrow.-kind/filter-or-other.html)

The signature of 
`filterOrElse` is

```
inline fun <A, B> EitherOf<A, B>
.filterOrElse(predicate: (B) -> Boolean, default: () -> A): Either<A, B>
```

and `filterOrOther` is

```
inline fun <A, B> EitherOf<A, B>
.filterOrOther(predicate: (B) -> Boolean, default: (B) -> A): Either<A, B>
```

The differnce i've seen is that `filterOrOther` has an argument `B` for `default` lambda.

> default: (**B**) -> A vs default: () -> A

But I think there is another reason to have two different functions. What is the reason? and what the difference between them?

Comment: According to the documentation, that's indeed the only difference.

Answer (score 3):

If the `predicate`'s outcome is `false`, `filterOrOther` gives you the option to use that argument `B` to generate `A` with `default`. `filterOrElse`'s `default` is simply a producer which doesn't use `B` to generate `A`.

Comment: in other word is it exactly what I said in the question?

Comment: Basically yes. It's important to note that the argument `B` used in `predicate` is the same one used in `default`. As for a reason, I'd said you can use `filterOrElse` to protect yourself (and/or other colleagues in bigger projects) from introducing weird/hacky side-effects caused by `B` in the `default` lambda. It's you saying "Use `B` in `predicate` ONLY, using `B` in `default` is a bad idea for <insert reason>".